# Cannot import data from table

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

First of all I'm new to this "scrapy" and "python" I recently started my CE degree, please be patient hahaha.
I'm trying to use the data from the table (site url: https://www.fundsexplorer.com.br/ranking) but with the guides I've seen about webscraping I just cannot scrape the data from the table of the site, I think that the structure of the table is pretty different of the simple ones I used to train lol.
I would be glad if someone could help me at least be able to scrape the data from the rows.

Thx a lot.

Here is the begining of the code I tried:

PS: I know its inomplete, it's because after about 4 hours in this project trying to get the data I just rage quitted lol.

```
import scrapy
    
    class FiispiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
        name = "fiispider"
        allowed_domains = ["fundsexplorer.com.br"]
        start_urls = ["https://fundsexplorer.com.br/ranking"]
    
        def parse(self, response):
            rows = response.css('table.default-fiis-table__container__table tr')
            for row in rows: 
                yield {
                    'name': 
                }
            
    
            #table = response.css('table.default-fiis-table__container__table')`
```

Comment: To format a block of code, either highlight the code and click the `{}` icon, or precede and follow the block with a line consisting of three backticks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data for the table is fetched dynamically. If you peek in the network tab of your browsers dev tools you will see that the data comes through an ajax call to https://www.fundsexplorer.com.br/wp-json/funds/v1/get-ranking . In order to get each of the rows you simply need to query the url, convert it from json, and then yield each of the rows in the object list.  You will also need to get the value of the `X-Funds-Nonce` token from the request headers in your browser as well and attach it to your scrapy request.

For example:

```py
import scrapy
import json

headers = {"X-Funds-Nonce":" 61495f60b533cc40ad822e054998a3190ea9bca0d94791a1da"}

class FiispiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "fiispider"
    allowed_domains = ["fundsexplorer.com.br"]
    
    def start_requests(self):
        start_urls = ["https://www.fundsexplorer.com.br/wp-json/funds/v1/get-ranking"]
        for url in start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url, headers=headers)

    def parse(self, response):
        for row in json.loads(response.json()):
            yield row
```

Partial Output

```bash
{'post_id': '451', 'ticker': 'WPLZ11', 'dividendo': '0.4000', 'yeld': '0.6500', 'media_yield_3m': '0.6267', 'soma_yield_3m': '1.8800', 'media_yield_6m': '0.6467', 'soma_yield_6m': '3.8800'
, 'media_yield_12m': '0.6467', 'soma_yield_12m': '7.7600', 'variacao_cotacao_mes': '-0.3710', 'rentabilidade': '-21.1828', 'rentabilidade_mes': '0.2766', 'cotacao_fechamento': '61.7600', '
soma_yield_ano_corrente': '3.1400', 'ano': '2023', 'vpa_yield': '0.5826', 'vpa': '102.9900', 'vpa_change': '0.0551', 'pl': '105130234.6700', 'vpa_rent': '4.6842', 'vpa_rent_m': '0.6380', '
yield_vpa_3m_sum': '1.5542', 'yield_vpa_3m': '0.5181', 'yield_vpa_6m_sum': '2.8665', 'yield_vpa_6m': '0.4778', 'yield_vpa_12m_sum': None, 'yield_vpa_12m': None, 'setor': 'Shoppings', 'seto
r_slug': 'shoppings', 'valor': '63.8', 'liquidezmediadiaria': '3339.61', 'patrimonio': '89762305.91', 'pvp': '0.7278', 'p_vpa': 0.6194776191863288, 'post_title': 'WPLZ11', 'v_fisica': None
, 'v_financeira': None, 'ativos': '1'}
2023-06-23 21:49:08 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.fundsexplorer.com.br/wp-json/funds/v1/get-ranking>
{'post_id': '365', 'ticker': 'WTSP11B', 'dividendo': '0.1900', 'yeld': '0.0000', 'media_yield_3m': '0.2000', 'soma_yield_3m': '0.6000', 'media_yield_6m': '0.5050', 'soma_yield_6m': '3.0300
', 'media_yield_12m': '0.6475', 'soma_yield_12m': '7.7700', 'variacao_cotacao_mes': '0.0000', 'rentabilidade': None, 'rentabilidade_mes': '0.0000', 'cotacao_fechamento': None, 'soma_yield_
ano_corrente': '1.7900', 'ano': '2023', 'vpa_yield': '0.4021', 'vpa': '78.9232', 'vpa_change': '0.6897', 'pl': '78336432.2500', 'vpa_rent': '5.1059', 'vpa_rent_m': '1.0946', 'yield_vpa_3m_
sum': None, 'yield_vpa_3m': None, 'yield_vpa_6m_sum': None, 'yield_vpa_6m': None, 'yield_vpa_12m_sum': None, 'yield_vpa_12m': None, 'setor': 'Misto', 'setor_slug': 'misto', 'valor': '35.05
', 'liquidezmediadiaria': '1071.09', 'patrimonio': '71950652.95', 'pvp': '0.4828', 'p_vpa': 0.4441026212824619, 'post_title': 'WTSP11B', 'v_fisica': None, 'v_financeira': None, 'ativos': '
2'}
2023-06-23 21:49:08 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.fundsexplorer.com.br/wp-json/funds/v1/get-ranking>
{'post_id': '516', 'ticker': 'XPCA11', 'dividendo': '0.1100', 'yeld': '1.1100', 'media_yield_3m': '1.3133', 'soma_yield_3m': '3.9400', 'media_yield_6m': '1.3367', 'soma_yield_6m': '8.0200'
, 'media_yield_12m': '1.3283', 'soma_yield_12m': '15.9400', 'variacao_cotacao_mes': '0.0000', 'rentabilidade': '10.1734', 'rentabilidade_mes': '1.1100', 'cotacao_fechamento': '9.9300', 'so
ma_yield_ano_corrente': '6.5600', 'ano': '2023', 'vpa_yield': '1.3699', 'vpa': '9.4900', 'vpa_change': '-0.0084', 'pl': '317410269.3900', 'vpa_rent': '14.0009', 'vpa_rent_m': '1.3613', 'yi
eld_vpa_3m_sum': '4.4239', 'yield_vpa_3m': '1.4746', 'yield_vpa_6m_sum': '8.8416', 'yield_vpa_6m': '1.4736', 'yield_vpa_12m_sum': '15.9624', 'yield_vpa_12m': '1.4511', 'setor': 'Indefinido
', 'setor_slug': 'indefinido', 'valor': '9.55', 'liquidezmediadiaria': '1921021.24', 'patrimonio': '317410269.39', 'pvp': '1.0443', 'p_vpa': 1.0063224446786092, 'post_title': 'XPCA11', 'v_
fisica': None, 'v_financeira': None, 'ativos': '0'}
2023-06-23 21:49:08 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.fundsexplorer.com.br/wp-json/funds/v1/get-ranking>
{'post_id': '211', 'ticker': 'XPCI11', 'dividendo': '0.9300', 'yeld': '1.1100', 'media_yield_3m': '1.1167', 'soma_yield_3m': '3.3500', 'media_yield_6m': '1.1183', 'soma_yield_6m': '6.7100'
, 'media_yield_12m': '1.0308', 'soma_yield_12m': '12.3700', 'variacao_cotacao_mes': '4.7930', 'rentabilidade': '8.8637', 'rentabilidade_mes': '5.9562', 'cotacao_fechamento': '83.5200', 'so
ma_yield_ano_corrente': '5.8200', 'ano': '2023', 'vpa_yield': '0.6408', 'vpa': '93.6283', 'vpa_change': '-1.9679', 'pl': '814711734.7600', 'vpa_rent': '10.1113', 'vpa_rent_m': '-1.3397', '
yield_vpa_3m_sum': '2.2491', 'yield_vpa_3m': '0.7497', 'yield_vpa_6m_sum': '5.3563', 'yield_vpa_6m': '0.8927', 'yield_vpa_12m_sum': None, 'yield_vpa_12m': None, 'setor': 'Papéis', 'setor_s
lug': 'papeis', 'valor': '86.64', 'liquidezmediadiaria': '1830912.37', 'patrimonio': '816616393.65', 'pvp': '0.9126', 'p_vpa': 0.9253612422739707, 'post_title': 'XPCI11', 'v_fisica': None,
 'v_financeira': None, 'ativos': '0'}
2023-06-23 21:49:08 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.fundsexplorer.com.br/wp-json/funds/v1/get-ranking>
{'post_id': '347', 'ticker': 'XPCM11', 'dividendo': '0.0800', 'yeld': '0.5800', 'media_yield_3m': '0.6800', 'soma_yield_3m': '2.0400', 'media_yield_6m': '0.8550', 'soma_yield_6m': '5.1300'
, 'media_yield_12m': '0.8817', 'soma_yield_12m': '10.5800', 'variacao_cotacao_mes': '-1.7857', 'rentabilidade': '-0.6816', 'rentabilidade_mes': '-1.2161', 'cotacao_fechamento': '13.7500',
'soma_yield_ano_corrente': '3.5300', 'ano': '2023', 'vpa_yield': '0.3299', 'vpa': '51.5300', 'vpa_change': '-0.7746', 'pl': '124433063.4300', 'vpa_rent': '-2.9679', 'vpa_rent_m': '-0.4473'
, 'yield_vpa_3m_sum': '0.8485', 'yield_vpa_3m': '0.2828', 'yield_vpa_6m_sum': '1.7147', 'yield_vpa_6m': '0.2858', 'yield_vpa_12m_sum': None, 'yield_vpa_12m': None, 'setor': 'Lajes Corporat
ivas', 'setor_slug': 'lajes-corporativas', 'valor': '13.75', 'liquidezmediadiaria': '44398.63', 'patrimonio': '103295556.68', 'pvp': '0.3221', 'p_vpa': 0.26683485348340774, 'post_title': '
XPCM11', 'v_fisica': None, 'v_financeira': None, 'ativos': '1'}
2023-06-23 21:49:08 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.fundsexplorer.com.br/wp-json/funds/v1/get-ranking>
{'post_id': '222', 'ticker': 'XPHT11', 'dividendo': '1.6500', 'yeld': '1.4500', 'media_yield_3m': '1.3400', 'soma_yield_3m': '4.0200', 'media_yield_6m': '1.2867', 'soma_yield_6m': '7.7200'
, 'media_yield_12m': '1.0625', 'soma_yield_12m': '12.7500', 'variacao_cotacao_mes': '3.6273', 'rentabilidade': '8.2444', 'rentabilidade_mes': '5.1299', 'cotacao_fechamento': '113.9900', 's
oma_yield_ano_corrente': '6.2000', 'ano': '2023', 'vpa_yield': '1.5925', 'vpa': '94.1900', 'vpa_change': '-0.0775', 'pl': '358343595.7100', 'vpa_rent': '6.7411', 'vpa_rent_m': '1.5138', 'y
ield_vpa_3m_sum': '4.8834', 'yield_vpa_3m': '1.6278', 'yield_vpa_6m_sum': '6.2654', 'yield_vpa_6m': '1.0442', 'yield_vpa_12m_sum': None, 'yield_vpa_12m': None, 'setor': 'Hotéis', 'setor_sl
ug': 'hoteis', 'valor': '125', 'liquidezmediadiaria': '75306.65', 'patrimonio': '376512967.62', 'pvp': '1.2139', 'p_vpa': 1.3271047881940758, 'post_title': 'XPHT11', 'v_fisica': None, 'v_f
inanceira': None, 'ativos': '12'}
2023-06-23 21:49:08 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.fundsexplorer.com.br/wp-json/funds/v1/get-ranking>
{'post_id': '1850', 'ticker': 'XPID11', 'dividendo': '0.4500', 'yeld': '0.5100', 'media_yield_3m': '0.6500', 'soma_yield_3m': '1.9500', 'media_yield_6m': '0.7083', 'soma_yield_6m': '4.2500
', 'media_yield_12m': '0.7000', 'soma_yield_12m': '8.4000', 'variacao_cotacao_mes': '5.1749', 'rentabilidade': '7.4418', 'rentabilidade_mes': '5.7113', 'cotacao_fechamento': '87.8000', 'so
ma_yield_ano_corrente': '6.1700', 'ano': '2023', 'vpa_yield': None, 'vpa': None, 'vpa_change': None, 'pl': None, 'vpa_rent': None, 'vpa_rent_m': None, 'yield_vpa_3m_sum': None, 'yield_vpa_
3m': None, 'yield_vpa_6m_sum': None, 'yield_vpa_6m': None, 'yield_vpa_12m_sum': None, 'yield_vpa_12m': None, 'setor': 'Fundo de Desenvolvimento', 'setor_slug': 'fundo-de-desenvolvimento',
'valor': '86.99', 'liquidezmediadiaria': '644698.92', 'patrimonio': '0', 'pvp': '0', 'p_vpa': None, 'post_title': 'XPID11', 'v_fisica': None, 'v_financeira': None, 'ativos': ''}
2023-06-23 21:49:08 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.fundsexplorer.com.br/wp-json/funds/v1/get-ranking>
{'post_id': '396', 'ticker': 'XPIN11', 'dividendo': '0.6500', 'yeld': '0.8200', 'media_yield_3m': '0.8567', 'soma_yield_3m': '2.5700', 'media_yield_6m': '0.8817', 'soma_yield_6m': '5.2900'
, 'media_yield_12m': '0.8525', 'soma_yield_12m': '10.2300', 'variacao_cotacao_mes': '0.6878', 'rentabilidade': '11.6191', 'rentabilidade_mes': '1.5135', 'cotacao_fechamento': '79.0500', 's
oma_yield_ano_corrente': '4.4100', 'ano': '2023', 'vpa_yield': '0.6261', 'vpa': '103.8115', 'vpa_change': '-1.3709', 'pl': '742296242.1900', 'vpa_rent': '0.7513', 'vpa_rent_m': '-0.7533',
'yield_vpa_3m_sum': '1.8454', 'yield_vpa_3m': '0.6151', 'yield_vpa_6m_sum': '3.5387', 'yield_vpa_6m': '0.5898', 'yield_vpa_12m_sum': None, 'yield_vpa_12m': None, 'setor': 'Imóveis Industri
ais e Logísticos', 'setor_slug': 'imoveis-industriais-e-logisticos', 'valor': '80', 'liquidezmediadiaria': '416218', 'patrimonio': '729955133.15', 'pvp': '0.7822', 'p_vpa': 0.7706275316318
52, 'post_title': 'XPIN11', 'v_fisica': None, 'v_financeira': None, 'ativos': '98'}
2023-06-23 21:49:08 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.fundsexplorer.com.br/wp-json/funds/v1/get-ranking>
{'post_id': '275', 'ticker': 'XPLG11', 'dividendo': '0.7500', 'yeld': '0.7100', 'media_yield_3m': '0.7433', 'soma_yield_3m': '2.2300', 'media_yield_6m': '0.7633', 'soma_yield_6m': '4.5800'
, 'media_yield_12m': '0.7350', 'soma_yield_12m': '8.8200', 'variacao_cotacao_mes': '5.9000', 'rentabilidade': '11.0401', 'rentabilidade_mes': '6.6519', 'cotacao_fechamento': '105.9000', 's
oma_yield_ano_corrente': '3.8300', 'ano': '2023', 'vpa_yield': '0.6463', 'vpa': '114.4897', 'vpa_change': '0.1879', 'pl': '3102791995.7500', 'vpa_rent': '11.4711', 'vpa_rent_m': '0.8355',
'yield_vpa_3m_sum': '1.9418', 'yield_vpa_3m': '0.6473', 'yield_vpa_6m_sum': '3.8230', 'yield_vpa_6m': '0.6372', 'yield_vpa_12m_sum': None, 'yield_vpa_12m': None, 'setor': 'Imóveis Industri
ais e Logísticos', 'setor_slug': 'imoveis-industriais-e-logisticos', 'valor': '112.12', 'liquidezmediadiaria': '3947504.74', 'patrimonio': '3073592158.93', 'pvp': '0.9884', 'p_vpa': 0.9793
020682209841, 'post_title': 'XPLG11', 'v_fisica': None, 'v_financeira': None, 'ativos': '19'}
2023-06-23 21:49:08 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.fundsexplorer.com.br/wp-json/funds/v1/get-ranking>
{'post_id': '373', 'ticker': 'XPML11', 'dividendo': '0.8100', 'yeld': '0.7800', 'media_yield_3m': '0.7900', 'soma_yield_3m': '2.3700', 'media_yield_6m': '0.8117', 'soma_yield_6m': '4.8700'
, 'media_yield_12m': '0.7717', 'soma_yield_12m': '9.2600', 'variacao_cotacao_mes': '1.2136', 'rentabilidade': '9.8169', 'rentabilidade_mes': '2.0031', 'cotacao_fechamento': '104.2500', 'so
ma_yield_ano_corrente': '3.9600', 'ano': '2023', 'vpa_yield': '0.7603', 'vpa': '101.2739', 'vpa_change': '-0.6573', 'pl': '2057877597.2300', 'vpa_rent': '6.5638', 'vpa_rent_m': '0.0981', '
yield_vpa_3m_sum': '2.2317', 'yield_vpa_3m': '0.7439', 'yield_vpa_6m_sum': None, 'yield_vpa_6m': None, 'yield_vpa_12m_sum': None, 'yield_vpa_12m': None, 'setor': 'Shoppings', 'setor_slug':
 'shoppings', 'valor': '103.91', 'liquidezmediadiaria': '5638116.11', 'patrimonio': '2098002886.54', 'pvp': '1.0585', 'p_vpa': 1.0260294113290789, 'post_title': 'XPML11', 'v_fisica': None,
 'v_financeira': None, 'ativos': '12'}
2023-06-23 21:49:08 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.fundsexplorer.com.br/wp-json/funds/v1/get-ranking>
{'post_id': '345', 'ticker': 'XPPR11', 'dividendo': '0.1000', 'yeld': '0.4300', 'media_yield_3m': '0.4167', 'soma_yield_3m': '1.2500', 'media_yield_6m': '0.5717', 'soma_yield_6m': '3.4300'
, 'media_yield_12m': '0.6400', 'soma_yield_12m': '7.6800', 'variacao_cotacao_mes': '1.4680', 'rentabilidade': '-25.3158', 'rentabilidade_mes': '1.9044', 'cotacao_fechamento': '23.5000', 's
oma_yield_ano_corrente': '2.5000', 'ano': '2023', 'vpa_yield': '0.4012', 'vpa': '74.7687', 'vpa_change': '0.0522', 'pl': '547020346.8600', 'vpa_rent': '-3.6491', 'vpa_rent_m': '0.4536', 'y
ield_vpa_3m_sum': '1.1993', 'yield_vpa_3m': '0.3998', 'yield_vpa_6m_sum': '2.5088', 'yield_vpa_6m': '0.4181', 'yield_vpa_12m_sum': None, 'yield_vpa_12m': None, 'setor': 'Lajes Corporativas
', 'setor_slug': 'lajes-corporativas', 'valor': '23.08', 'liquidezmediadiaria': '260064.03', 'patrimonio': '521188970.44', 'pvp': '0.3255', 'p_vpa': 0.3086853188566874, 'post_title': 'XPPR
11', 'v_fisica': None, 'v_financeira': None, 'ativos': '5'}
2023-06-23 21:49:08 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.fundsexplorer.com.br/wp-json/funds/v1/get-ranking>
{'post_id': '399', 'ticker': 'XPSF11', 'dividendo': '0.0760', 'yeld': '1.0200', 'media_yield_3m': '1.0600', 'soma_yield_3m': '3.1800', 'media_yield_6m': '1.0517', 'soma_yield_6m': '6.3100'
, 'media_yield_12m': '1.0208', 'soma_yield_12m': '12.2500', 'variacao_cotacao_mes': '5.3824', 'rentabilidade': '3.1943', 'rentabilidade_mes': '6.4573', 'cotacao_fechamento': '7.4400', 'som
a_yield_ano_corrente': '5.3000', 'ano': '2023', 'vpa_yield': '0.9016', 'vpa': '8.5400', 'vpa_change': '-4.0449', 'pl': '369792382.0500', 'vpa_rent': '-89.4039', 'vpa_rent_m': '-3.1798', 'y
ield_vpa_3m_sum': '2.6153', 'yield_vpa_3m': '0.8718', 'yield_vpa_6m_sum': '5.1091', 'yield_vpa_6m': '0.8515', 'yield_vpa_12m_sum': None, 'yield_vpa_12m': None, 'setor': 'Fundo de Fundos',
'setor_slug': 'fundo-de-fundos', 'valor': '8.04', 'liquidezmediadiaria': '588485.76', 'patrimonio': '365478307.57', 'pvp': '0.9455', 'p_vpa': 0.9414519906323185, 'post_title': 'XPSF11', 'v
_fisica': None, 'v_financeira': None, 'ativos': '0'}
2023-06-23 21:49:08 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.fundsexplorer.com.br/wp-json/funds/v1/get-ranking>
{'post_id': '174', 'ticker': 'XTED11', 'dividendo': '11.1600', 'yeld': None, 'media_yield_3m': None, 'soma_yield_3m': None, 'media_yield_6m': None, 'soma_yield_6m': None, 'media_yield_12m'
: None, 'soma_yield_12m': None, 'variacao_cotacao_mes': None, 'rentabilidade': None, 'rentabilidade_mes': None, 'cotacao_fechamento': None, 'soma_yield_ano_corrente': None, 'ano': None, 'v
pa_yield': '0.0000', 'vpa': '28.0218', 'vpa_change': '-0.3575', 'pl': '50230589.4700', 'vpa_rent': '-3.4450', 'vpa_rent_m': '-0.3575', 'yield_vpa_3m_sum': '0.0000', 'yield_vpa_3m': '0.0000
', 'yield_vpa_6m_sum': '0.0000', 'yield_vpa_6m': '0.0000', 'yield_vpa_12m_sum': '0.0000', 'yield_vpa_12m': '0.0000', 'setor': 'Lajes Corporativas', 'setor_slug': 'lajes-corporativas', 'val
or': '8.82', 'liquidezmediadiaria': '17641.88', 'patrimonio': '67378204.04', 'pvp': '0.6771', 'p_vpa': 0.3147549407960945, 'post_title': 'XTED11', 'v_fisica': None, 'v_financeira': None, '
ativos': '1'}
2023-06-23 21:49:08 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.fundsexplorer.com.br/wp-json/funds/v1/get-ranking>
{'post_id': '175', 'ticker': 'YUFI11', 'dividendo': '0.1524', 'yeld': '0.1500', 'media_yield_3m': '0.1300', 'soma_yield_3m': '0.3900', 'media_yield_6m': '0.0650', 'soma_yield_6m': '0.3900'
, 'media_yield_12m': '0.0433', 'soma_yield_12m': '0.3900', 'variacao_cotacao_mes': '0.0000', 'rentabilidade': None, 'rentabilidade_mes': '0.0000', 'cotacao_fechamento': '105.0000', 'soma_y
ield_ano_corrente': '0.3900', 'ano': '2023', 'vpa_yield': None, 'vpa': None, 'vpa_change': None, 'pl': None, 'vpa_rent': None, 'vpa_rent_m': None, 'yield_vpa_3m_sum': None, 'yield_vpa_3m':
 None, 'yield_vpa_6m_sum': None, 'yield_vpa_6m': None, 'yield_vpa_12m_sum': None, 'yield_vpa_12m': None, 'setor': 'Fundo de Desenvolvimento', 'setor_slug': 'fundo-de-desenvolvimento', 'val
or': '80.84', 'liquidezmediadiaria': '2895.93', 'patrimonio': '50073483.72', 'pvp': '0.7954', 'p_vpa': None, 'post_title': 'YUFI11', 'v_fisica': None, 'v_financeira': None, 'ativos': '28'}

2023-06-23 21:49:08 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.fundsexplorer.com.br/wp-json/funds/v1/get-ranking>
{'post_id': '537', 'ticker': 'YUFI11B', 'dividendo': '0.6331', 'yeld': '0.0000', 'media_yield_3m': '0.0000', 'soma_yield_3m': '0.0000', 'media_yield_6m': '0.0000', 'soma_yield_6m': '0.0000
', 'media_yield_12m': '0.0000', 'soma_yield_12m': '0.0000', 'variacao_cotacao_mes': '0.0000', 'rentabilidade': '0.0000', 'rentabilidade_mes': '0.0000', 'cotacao_fechamento': '0.0000', 'som
a_yield_ano_corrente': None, 'ano': '2022', 'vpa_yield': '0.5999', 'vpa': '105.5322', 'vpa_change': '-0.0137', 'pl': '41701052.9800', 'vpa_rent': '6.3235', 'vpa_rent_m': '0.5861', 'yield_v
pa_3m_sum': None, 'yield_vpa_3m': None, 'yield_vpa_6m_sum': None, 'yield_vpa_6m': None, 'yield_vpa_12m_sum': None, 'yield_vpa_12m': None, 'setor': 'Indefinido', 'setor_slug': 'indefinido',
 'valor': None, 'liquidezmediadiaria': None, 'patrimonio': None, 'pvp': None, 'p_vpa': None, 'post_title': 'YUFI11B', 'v_fisica': None, 'v_financeira': None, 'ativos': '0'}
2023-06-23 21:49:08 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.fundsexplorer.com.br/wp-json/funds/v1/get-ranking>
{'post_id': '1866', 'ticker': 'ZAVI11', 'dividendo': '1.1000', 'yeld': '0.8700', 'media_yield_3m': '0.8700', 'soma_yield_3m': '2.6100', 'media_yield_6m': '0.8617', 'soma_yield_6m': '5.1700
', 'media_yield_12m': '0.8686', 'soma_yield_12m': '6.0800', 'variacao_cotacao_mes': '0.0000', 'rentabilidade': '1.0929', 'rentabilidade_mes': '0.8700', 'cotacao_fechamento': '126.0000', 's
oma_yield_ano_corrente': '4.2300', 'ano': '2023', 'vpa_yield': None, 'vpa': None, 'vpa_change': None, 'pl': None, 'vpa_rent': None, 'vpa_rent_m': None, 'yield_vpa_3m_sum': None, 'yield_vpa
_3m': None, 'yield_vpa_6m_sum': None, 'yield_vpa_6m': None, 'yield_vpa_12m_sum': None, 'yield_vpa_12m': None, 'setor': 'Indefinido', 'setor_slug': 'indefinido', 'valor': '125.8', 'liquidez
mediadiaria': '93518.97', 'patrimonio': '118026295.42', 'pvp': '0.9891', 'p_vpa': None, 'post_title': 'ZAVI11', 'v_fisica': None, 'v_financeira': None, 'ativos': '8'}
2023-06-23 21:49:08 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.fundsexplorer.com.br/wp-json/funds/v1/get-ranking>
{'post_id': '295', 'ticker': 'ZIFI11', 'dividendo': '3.3050', 'yeld': '0.0000', 'media_yield_3m': '0.0000', 'soma_yield_3m': '0.0000', 'media_yield_6m': '0.0000', 'soma_yield_6m': '0.0000'
, 'media_yield_12m': '0.0000', 'soma_yield_12m': '0.0000', 'variacao_cotacao_mes': '0.0000', 'rentabilidade': None, 'rentabilidade_mes': '0.0000', 'cotacao_fechamento': None, 'soma_yield_a
no_corrente': '0.0000', 'ano': '2022', 'vpa_yield': None, 'vpa': None, 'vpa_change': None, 'pl': None, 'vpa_rent': None, 'vpa_rent_m': None, 'yield_vpa_3m_sum': None, 'yield_vpa_3m': None,
 'yield_vpa_6m_sum': None, 'yield_vpa_6m': None, 'yield_vpa_12m_sum': None, 'yield_vpa_12m': None, 'setor': 'Fundo de Desenvolvimento', 'setor_slug': 'fundo-de-desenvolvimento', 'valor': '
1000', 'liquidezmediadiaria': '12438.73', 'patrimonio': '57357479.19', 'pvp': '0.8279', 'p_vpa': None, 'post_title': 'ZIFI11', 'v_fisica': None, 'v_financeira': None, 'ativos': '0'}
```

Comment: Wow, I really didn't have a clue about that, as I said, I'm new to this world and you helped me A LOT, thank you so much! 
My idea was to extract the data from this table to help my dad to get it easier and use this CSV, and this code is on point!